# batch predictions google automl via python

Tags: python, batch-processing, predict, multilabel-classification, automl

I'm pretty new using stackoverflow as well as using the google cloud platform, so apologies if am not asking this question in the right format. I am currently facing an issue with getting the predictions from my model.

I've trained a multilabel automl model on the google cloud platform and and now i want to use that model to score out new data entries.
Since the platform only allows one entry at the same time i want to make use of python to do batch predictions.

I've stored my data entries in seperate .txt files on the google cloud bucket and created a .txt file where i'm listing the gs:// references to those files (like they recommend in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/predict)).

I've exported a .json file with my credentials from the service account and specified the id's and paths in my code:

```
# import API credentials and specify model / path references
path = 'xxx.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = path

model_name = 'xxx'
model_id = 'TCN1234567890'
project_id = '1234567890'
model_full_id = f"https://eu-automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/locations/eu/models/{model_id}"
input_uri = f"gs://bucket_name/{model_name}/file_list.txt"
output_uri = f"gs://bucket_name/{model_name}/outputs/"
prediction_client = automl.PredictionServiceClient()
```

And then i'm running the following code to get the predictions:

```
# score batch of file_list
gcs_source = automl.GcsSource(input_uris=[input_uri])

input_config = automl.BatchPredictInputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source)
gcs_destination = automl.GcsDestination(output_uri_prefix=output_uri)
output_config = automl.BatchPredictOutputConfig(
    gcs_destination=gcs_destination
)

response = prediction_client.batch_predict(
    name=model_full_id,
    input_config=input_config,
    output_config=output_config
)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
print(
    f"Batch Prediction results saved to Cloud Storage bucket. {response.result()}"
)
```

However, i'm getting the following error: InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.

[image: print screen of the error]

Would anyone have a hince what is causing this issue?
Any input would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!

I needed to set the client to the 'eu' environment first:

```
options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='eu-automl.googleapis.com')
prediction_client = automl.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)
```